# how to change the font size of a UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle cell on iphone 3.0

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I know you previously change the font size of a cell like so:

```
cell.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
```

I'm using a cell that is init'd with the style UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle. How do I change the font size of the textlabel and detailtextlabel of this type of cell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
```

3.0 changed the UITableViewCell API.  I would suggest reading up on it in the docs as there are some deprecated methods

Answer (score 2):

You can have master font settings in a variable and assign it whenever is needed

```
UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10];    
cell.textLabel.font = cellFont;
```